# How to reverse command line compilation error output?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

Whenever a compilation results in an error output longer then one screen, I have to scroll back to see the first error (possibly a cause of the later ones) and fix it. This is especially a pain in Screen, where I first have to press ctrl+a Esc to scroll.

Is there a command line switch in `javac` that lets the error messages be displayed in reverse order, or is there some generic command line magic I can achieve the same effect with?

Update: Just to clarify, I always use the command line for compilation, an IDE is not an option.

Comment: How about using an IDE?

Comment: On a Linux, there is naturally a trivial way: `javac ... | tail -r` But personally, I'd use `javac ... | less`, which automatically gives me the first screen of output.

Comment: @assylias see my update, I can’t stand IDEs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Tail complains there is no -r switch. Oddly, less scrolls the output to the end, as if it weren’t piped through it at all.

Comment: @JoóÁdám Then you probably don't realise what you are missing...

Comment: @assylias I tried several times, I swear. They just always screw up on UX somewhere…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stop on the first compilation error, then you should probably use `-Xmaxerrs 1`. You can fix that error and compile again.

**Edit**
If you are under *nix environment, redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` will make most of the tools like `head`, `more`, `less` work. Compilation errors are printed to `stderr`.

```
javac File.java 2>&1 | less
```

**Edit2**
You could also send it to a file using `-Xstdout filename`

Comment: Technically not an answer to the question, but I will accept it, because `-Xmaxerrs 1` works really nice for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to `more` on command-line or better use an IDE like Eclipse.

```
javac file.java | more
```

Now press *space bar* to let the output scroll (or *enter* for line by line) if it's more than one screen page.

Comment: `more`, just like `less`, displays the entire output, scrolling to the last line (which I don’t understand either).

Comment: That's indicative of a program writing info to *stderr*, not *stdout*.

Comment: @RichardSitze Yeah, it crossed my mind, but I thought at the end of the day by default the pipe takes both stdout and stderr.